# Can I get all assemblies referenced by a website

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically, I want to print a list on a page inside my MVC site that shows all the assemblies that are used by the application and there version information.

I don't want to just include those in the bin directory, I want to use a more accurate way.

So examples would be

I want to know which dll's within the bin directory are being used.  For each of these, I need to see what their dependent assemblies are (with their version information).

I want to know which dll's are referenced from GAC, etc.

I want as much information on this as possible, so information like what version the assembly is expecting, and what the application is picking up would be useful.

Are there any standard approaches to this?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [`BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which:

> Returns a list of assembly references that all page compilations must reference.

Example usage:

```
var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();
```

Note also an important difference between this method and `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`. `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies` returns:

> assemblies specified in the assemblies element of the Web.config file, assemblies built from custom code in the App_Code directory, and assemblies in other top-level folders.

while `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` returns only assemblies currently loaded.

Comment: would this also return assemblies that are referenced but are sourced from GAC.

Comment: @Martin, yes. Of course the simplest way is to try it :)

Comment: I beg to differ, it's simpler and easier to ask someone who knows the answer than to build and test a solution.  Less wasted time that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```